# Как отбросить символы в тексте, состоящим из 2000 и более символов, до этих 2000 символов на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, wikipedia

Я пытаюсь сделать дискорд бота википедию, который получает запрос и выдаёт ответ исходя из представленной информации. Проблема заключается в том, что некоторые ответы из википедии состоят из количества символов, которое недопустимо в дискорде.

Для запросов из википедии использую вот такой код:

```
a = wikipedia.summary(input("Введите запрос: "))
```

А для отбрасывания символов использовал:

```
print('.'.join(a.split('.')[:-1]))
```

Этот код для "отбрасывания" не помог...
Помогите вы, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрезать до 2000 символов, потом обрезать до последней точки (убрать последнее незаконченное предложение), или оставить как есть (если точка не нашлась):

```
# "qwer. tyui. yui".rpartition('.') -> ("qwer. tyui", ".", " yui")
# "qwer tyui yui".rpartition('.') -> ("", "", "qwer tyui yui")
left, dot, right = text[:2000].rpartition('.')  
text = left + dot if left else right  # вернуть left + dot, если в left что-то есть, иначе вернуть right
print(text)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только уже с этим есть проблема, ведь мне выдаёт пустой вывод (прилагаю код самой программы)
```import wikipedia

while True:
    wikipedia.set_lang("ru")
    a = wikipedia.summary(input("Введите запрос: "))
    left, dot, right = a[:2000].rpartition('.')
    text = left + dot if left else right```

Comment: Пробовали `print(text)` в конце добавить?

Comment: Да, я добавил, немного дописал и всё заработало, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
print('.'.join(a.split('.')[:-1]))
```

Этот ваш код отбрасывает из текста последнее предложение (если считать, что предложения разделены именно точками).

Если хотите взять просто 2000 первых символов, то возьмите соответственный срез от текста:

```
print(a[:2000])
```